# Laravel Mix webpack scss compile error on multiply inside for loop

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I have a problem, with I guess webpack.

I have a Laravel 5.6 installation which compiles scss to css through Laravel Mix with webpack. (I also installed TailwindCSS, but that should work fine.)

I have the following SCSS:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    p.animated-opacity, a.animated-opacity {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            animation-delay: #{$i} * 2s;
        }
    }

    input.animated-opacity, button.animated-opacity, select.animated-opacity {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            animation-delay: (2s * #{$i - 1}) + 1s;
        }
    }
}
```

Which compiles itself with Laravel Mix and webpack to:

```
main p.animated-opacity:nth-child(1),
main a.animated-opacity:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1 * 2s;
    animation-delay: 1 * 2s;
}

main input.animated-opacity:nth-child(1),
main button.animated-opacity:nth-child(1),
main select.animated-opacity:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s * 0 + 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s * 0 + 1s;
}

main p.animated-opacity:nth-child(2),
main a.animated-opacity:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2 * 2s;
    animation-delay: 2 * 2s;
}
```

and onward, untill it reaches the tenth child. However, it **should** compile to:

```
main p.animated-opacity:nth-child(1),
main a.animated-opacity:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

main input.animated-opacity:nth-child(1),
main button.animated-opacity:nth-child(1),
main select.animated-opacity:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

main p.animated-opacity:nth-child(2),
main a.animated-opacity:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

What am I, or is Laravel Mix/Webpack doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, by wrapping the number of seconds in a calc() it works, and browsers render it correctly. The SCSS is now:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    p.animated-opacity, a.animated-opacity {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            animation-delay: calc(#{$i} * 2s);
        }
    }

    input.animated-opacity, button.animated-opacity, select.animated-opacity, label.animated-opacity {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            animation-delay: calc((2s * #{$i - 1}) + 1s);
        }
    }
}
```